# Receiving Apache access and error logs via rsyslog and possible catchall filter

Tags: apache-2.2, syslog, rsyslog

I'm new to rsyslog and have been trying to figure out why I am not receiving any of my Apache and mysql logs which are configured on the client-side to sent via rsyslog.  I am currently receiving all other types of logs from all my hosts except Apache and mysql.  I am assuming something is wrong with my filter directive on the server side.  Below is a copy of the directives I configured for mysql and apache.

```
$template PerHostApacheError,"/syslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/error.log"
$template PerHostApacheAccess,"/syslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/%msg:R,ERE,1,ZERO:imp:([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.--end%-access.log"
$template PerHostMySqld,"/syslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/mysql.log"
```

My question is do the above directives on the server side look correct? If not, how are they supposed to look like.  The documentation doesn't really show examples of how it should be used, but more of what each one does.  Also, is there an option to catch all messages that don't have a directive defined - for example log all other messages not defined via a directive to a catchall.log file on a per host basis. Something like:

```
$template PerHostCatchAll,"/syslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/catchall.log
```

Thanks for the help in advance.